How much it costs to build a prototype of the following patent (Remote magnetic manipulation of nervous systems)?
This is a two part patent: the first one explain the principles, the second one has an application. Its about interfering with a human nervous system with extremely weak magnetic fields.
Magnetic excitation of sensory resonances
https://patents.google.com/patent/US5935054A/en?inventor=Hendricus+G.+Loos
Remote magnetic manipulation of nervous systems
https://patents.google.com/patent/US6238333B1/en?inventor=Hendricus+G.+Loos

Seams to be something else, here low frequency magnetic fields, the other question is related to potentiallly dangerous GHz RF signals.

The referenced duplicate question does not apply to this question.
